# How to Authenticate users with specific table other than users table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a **users** table already.
I need to log my user in base on another table `babies` in my database.

/config/auth.php

I've tried adding a guard

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    ------------------------------------------------ Added 
    'baby' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'babies'
    ],


],
```

and a provider

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

     ------------------------------------------------ Added 

    'babies' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Baby::class,
    ],

],
```

and tried the attempt like this :

```
$auth = Auth::guard('baby')->attempt([
    'email' => strtolower(Request::get('email')),
    'password' => Request::get('password'),
    'status' => 1
]);
```

## It works ... my `$auth` returns true

but I have no idea how to access the current `Auth::Baby` or `Auth::Object`.

Can someone please give me some directions?

Comment: Why is "baby" not just a type of user? Without more context this smells like a design flaw

Comment: Now, that you get point/context, I already logged user in base on a diff table, but not sure how to access the Auth::check(), Auth::logout() and so forth...

Comment: I have a list of parents with babies information in my babies table, and I want to log parents and check which parent is current logged in so I can add my logic base on that.

Comment: `Auth::guard('baby')->check()` is what I am looking for.

Comment: If this is going to be a separate application then develop it as a separate application, and use the users table as normal for login. You can host more than one application on the same server, if you need a place for testing.

Comment: `$baby = Auth::guard('baby')->user(); $defaultUser = Auth::guard('web')->user();` to retrieve different models. 
`$isBabyLogged = Auth::guard('baby')->check(); $isDefaulrUserLogged = Auth::guard('web')->check();` - just to check. Also you can use middleware `auth:baby` - to restrict access

Comment: @yaroslawww gave you the answer. As you can see in the `config/auth.php` file, there is a default. Usually `users`. Just like with `config/filesystems.php` and `config/database.php` you can specify other options. @ADyson is right too. You may consider another approach to simplify your Laravel app. Sooner or later you will run into problems that will be hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

`$baby = Auth::guard('baby')->user();` `$defaultUser = Auth::guard('web')->user();` or `Auth::user();` to retrieve logged in user. `$isBabyLogged = Auth::guard('baby')->check();` `$isDefaulrUserLogged = Auth::guard('web')->check();` or `Auth::check();` - to check if the user is logged in.